# Drilling into wall opposite an ADT control panel — voltage detector going crazy, is this a no-go?

Tags: wiring, drywall, drill

First, I’m very inexperienced. I’m trying to hang a mirror on a wall, but the opposite side of the wall has a newer “smart home” ADT control panel. I figured there’d be some wiring to avoid, but my Fluke VoltAlert pen (2AC/90-1000V) just lights up every place on the wall within about 3 feet from the panel on the other side. Similarly with my voltage detecting stud finder - beeping along every spot on the entire section of wall I was going to drill into, with no distinct pathway of wires that I can detect.
Is there maybe a giant electrical panel in the wall behind the ADT Smart Home interface panel that could be causing this? Am I SOL or is there another way to determine if/where I can drill?

Comment: When you say "control panel", are you talking about the keypad on the wall, or the big unit with the batteries and such inside a cabinet in the wall?

Comment: push a sewing pin through the drywall in several places ... see if you hit anything solid

Comment: It’s a keypad on the wall, hardwired in. This exact unit: https://www.adt.com/security-keypad

Answer (score 1):

If that ADT control panel is recessed into the wall between two studs then you will likely need to avoid drilling anywhere behind it from the other side of that wall. I would leave a working margin of an additional 3 to 4 inches along the sides and tops.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the ADT panel and see if it is recessed into the wall. If so, where are the wires leaving the panel? (From the bottom, top, one side, the other side, both sides, all over?) If the wires are exit the panel vertically and not horizontally (out the sides) you can safely focus on finding the studs. IF they go out the sides then measure the height(s) the exit the box and mark it on the opposite side with a 2" margin of error. Drop your stud finder down a foot or two, or go up a foot or two and look for the studs. If they are too sensitive try looking for a stud over and then two and three studs over to get an idea of spacing. (16" O.C. 24" O.C.,). Come back and verify the stud location by drilling no deeper than 1" into the stud. You may have to shut off the ADT panel completely while looking for studs, especially if it has wireless functionality that is interfering with your equipment.

Electrical wiring is required to be deeper than standard sheetrock anchors, so fasteners that go into a stud are allowed one inch of penetration. This means your fasteners can be 1" + cladding thickness + hanger thickness. Generally 1-1/2" to 1-5/8". Be warned that not all wiring is properly placed or secured within a wall so if unsure, leave it alone.

Some rental centers that have tools have a camera you can rent that would allow you to drill 1/2" hole in the cavity to look around. I usually cut a hole the size of a low voltage single box (2-1/4"w x 3-5/8"H) to peak, at the same height as floor outlets or wall switches. Then use a remodel box and blank plate to cover the hole. Smartphone cameras or mirrors have made this easy. I will use a box cutter and trace the lines over and over until through.

Comment: Part of the issue is that the OP probably doesn't want to hit the enclosure itself